# navigation for one-page site with url

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hyperlink

I have a one-page site and links on them like `<a href="#block1">link1</a>`. Browser adress bar shows **site.com/#block1**

I want the browser gave a line like **site.com/block1** and after click on link **site.com/block1** browser will open scrolled page to needed block.

This jsfiddle as simple, but it isn't work  http://jsfiddle.net/26LRA/2/

There should be no magic, no php, cms, sql and different plugins. Only pure javascript/jquery

Add: I give you this site http://www.ascensionlatorre.com as that I want, but I can not understand their code

Comment: Have you tried using history.js cause your reference site is using it. The HTML5 history API wouldn't work very well cross browser for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to just visibly change the url:

```
$("#name0 a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+id).offset().top}, 'fast');
    window.history.pushState("", "", '/' + id);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HLBhm/)

for the link to actually work you need `mod_rewrite`, make a `.htaccess` and add:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ /index.php/#$1 [QSA,NE]
```

to read the URL

```
var path = document.location.pathname;
path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'), 1);
if(path){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+path).offset().top}, 'fast');
}
```

Comment: And I want the links to work, but when you click on the link site.com/block1 browser does an 404-error. I edited the top post

Comment: This all great, but if you send to browser link site.com/block1 it give you a 404-error

Comment: Ok, what rule i need add, if my block name "portfolio" witout digits, i can not understand '(.*)' this needed or not

Comment: `RewriteRule ^portfolio$ /index.html#portfolio [QSA,NE]`

Comment: Bassically you can make for every word `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html#$1 [QSA,NE]`

Comment: isn't work :(. My page named index.php, I create .htaccess and write inside:
AddDefaultCharset windows-utf-8
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^portfolio$ /index.php#portfolio [QSA,NE]

right?

Comment: Ok, works this `RewriteRule ^portfolio$ /index.php/#portfolio [QSA,NE]` But page load without move to this block

Comment: Page is loaded, but without moving to needed block

Comment: How to make the browser to navigate to the desired block?

Comment: Ok, this works, but in adress-bar again give a string with `#`. On the site `http://www.ascensionlatorre.com` it works as I want. how they did it?

Answer (score -1):

I think the proper way to do this would be to use mod_rewrite in your .htaccess.